# Residue classes of Z/pZ where p is odd?

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic, quotient-spaces

can someone help me with this problem. I have no idea where to start.

What I have so far:

$[a]^{(p-1)} = [1] \Rightarrow [a]^{(p-1)/2} = [1]^{1/2} = [1]$ ?

In the problem it should read. a is not divisible by p. ( I am assuming)[image]

Comment: so can I do $[a]^{(p-1)} = 1 \Rightarrow [a]^{(p-1)/2} = (1)^{1/2} = 1$ ?

Comment: You're right that “not divisible by $a$” should be “not divisible by $p$”.

Comment: I don't see then how I can break it into two cases?

Comment: $[1]^{1/2}\neq [1]$. Note that there are two distinct residue classes in $\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z$ that square to $[1]$, both $[1]$ and $[-1]$.  Note that the representative we pick to denote $[-1]$ is generally $[p-1]$, but as residue classes they are identical.

It's worth mentioning that $a^{\frac{p-1}{2}}\pmod{p}$ is one definition of $\left(\frac{a}{p}\right)$, the Legendre symbol.  Can you translate this problem into terms of this?  What are two natural cases that the legendre symbol encompasses?

Answer (score 1):

Let $g$ be a primitive root of $\Bbb{Z}_p$ and let $e = g^{\frac{p-1}{2}}$, then whe have $e^2 = 1$. Since $e \neq 1$ because $\frac{p-1}{2} \neq p-1$ we must have $e = -1$. For an arbitrary alement $a = g^r$ we have $a^{\frac{p-1}{2}} = (-1)^r$ establishing the correspondence with quadratic residues.

Answer (score 0):

Let $x=[a]^{\frac{p-1}{2}}$ then $x^2=[1]$ 
Now $x^2-[1]=(x-[1])(x-[-1])$ thus since $\mathbb{Z}_p$ is a integral domain, actually a field, either $x-[1]=0$ or  $x-[-1]=0$.